# Why my code is not converting the SortedSet to an Array

Tags: java

I am inputting a string from the user and then sorting the list in first step and then removing the duplicates in the second step.But the code is giving error.Please help!!!

Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;

class stringSort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s1;
        char[]s2;
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        s1=s.next();
        //call the sort method to sort the string
        s2=sort(s1);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(s2));
        //remove duplicate entries in the sorted string
        SortedSet<Character> set=new TreeSet<Character>();
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(set.toArray()));
    }
    static char[] sort(String s)
    {
        char []temp=s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(temp);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

It gives the error

`no suitable method found for addAll(List<char[]>)
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2));`

Comment: With a 1000+ reputation you should be able to tell what's the error.. post it please.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what error you get?

Comment: Why not to use `set.toArray()` instead? Also, `SortedSet<char` is invalid, it should be `SortedSet<Character>`.

Comment: please post the stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the code is giving error

```
SortedSet<char> set=new TreeSet<char>();
```

This is illegal and won't compile. If you want to use a character set you have to use the `Character` class.

```
SortedSet<Character> set=new TreeSet<Character>();
```

---

**UPDATE**

> It gives the error no suitable method found for addAll(List) set.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2));

That's because you need a `Character` array, not a `char` array, so you have two options:

1. Change `char[]s2;` to `Character[]s2;`
2. Convert the `char` array to a `Character` array before calling the `sort` method:

   ```
   Character[] a = new Character[s2.length];
   System.arraycopy(s2, 0, a, 0, s2.length);
   a = sort(s1);
   ```

In both cases you'll have to change your `sort` method to this:

```
static Character[] sort(String s) {
    Character[] temp = new Character[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }
    Arrays.sort(temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: +1. I didn't notice that :) More information: [Cannot Instantiate Generic Types with Primitive Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate).

Comment: @BackSlash:It gives the error `no suitable method found for addAll(List<char[]>)
  set.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2));
     ^
`